# REPLACE cannot accept varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am gettting the filenames in a folder into a temp table. I then use a cursor to do something to each of those filenames. When I try to replace the .bak string in filenames with `REPLACE`, it fails giving the error - Must declare the scalar variable "@FILENEME". Why ? How to fix it ?

Code -

```
CREATE TABLE ##FILES(
Name varchar(200),    
depth numeric,    
isFile numeric
)

--Assumption - the sp xp_dirtree has these columns 
- subdirectory, depth, file 
INSERT INTO ##FILES 
EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
MSSQL10_50.SS2008\MSSQL\Backup\', 10, 1


DECLARE @FILENAME AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @db AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name
    FROM ##FILES
    WHERE isFile = 1
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @db = REPLACE(@FILENEME, '.bak', '')
    print @db

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Comment: Can we delete this question ? It was a bad mistake. We can leave this here for comic purposes - How I made a lame mistake and how others answered the same thing in a row, as if there are 5 ways to correct the same typo.

Comment: You're not able to delete it yourself?

Comment: @admdrew - it has an upvoted answer so it can't be deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Simple typo in `REPLACE(@FILENEME, '.bak', '')`..

Use this  `REPLACE(@FILENAME, '.bak', '')`

---

```
CREATE TABLE ##FILES(
Name varchar(200),    
depth numeric,    
isFile numeric
)

--Assumption - the sp xp_dirtree has these columns 
- subdirectory, depth, file 
INSERT INTO ##FILES 
EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
MSSQL10_50.SS2008\MSSQL\Backup\', 10, 1


DECLARE @FILENAME AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @db AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name
    FROM ##FILES
    WHERE isFile = 1
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @db = REPLACE(@FILENAME, '.bak', '')
    print @db

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FILENAME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```